# IIS URL rewrite not working via search engines

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, search-engine

I have written a simple url rewrite rule for my website hosted in IIS 10. It works perfectly without any issue.

However, there is a strange behavior. When I write url directly in the browser rule works fine, but if I search url in Google/Bing and then click the url on search page, rule didn't trigger.

I looked into Insights didn't find any relevant information.

Here is the rule -

```
<rule name="PROD Rule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^myweb\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.mywebsite.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Writing url directly in browser -

*myweb.com*
redirects to https://www.mywebsite.com/

Searching url in search engine Google/Bing and then clicking url on search result page -

*myweb.com*
stays at *myweb.com*

I was expecting that the rules should trigger whenever request reaches IIS irrespective of source of origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out to be not a problem related to search engines. Instead it was just a missed case by rewrite rules I have written.

Existing rules were expecting *myweb.com* as input and correctly redirecting them to https://www.mywebsite.com/

However, when I search same url on search engine and click on them. Url send to server is NOT *myweb.com* instead *www.myweb.com*

Here is an update rules which worked -

```
<rule name="PROD Rule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^myweb\.com$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^threeinsure\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.mywebsite.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use below url rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="Force SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for responding late, actually to test this change I have to wait for next deployment. I'll confirm if this work as soon as I get my code on server. I have a question though, what was wrong with my rule and why this rule might work?

Comment: to check that what is the issue with your rule you need to run failed request tracing in iis.[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis)

Comment: This issue wasn't related to SSL. It was related to how search engines send urls to server. I have added an answer on how I fixed that.